# rsync not using the ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-agent

I have this running on gitlab ci, and it works for regular ssh (copied from the gitlab ci docs):

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
```

This gives me

```
Identity added: /dev/fd/63 (/dev/fd/63)
```

However, when I try to rsync I get an error:

```
Warning: Permanently added '*****' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
user@server: Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Why is rsync not able to use the identity added, when the ssh command is?

I can also do this instead, to work around the rsync issue.

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-add
```

Which gives me

```
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Which rsync **is** able to use, most likely because it's in the assumed place.

Does this mean rsync uses it's own ssh implementation and not the ssh-agent on the local system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the ssh protocol with rsync using the "-e" option.

```
rsync -e ssh file.tmp example.com:~/
```

Identity could also be provided in that option.

```
rsync -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" file.tmp exmple.com:~/
```